# Where is this quote from?

Tags: quotations, story-identification

This is consistent with the dictum that a person should earn a living by “the labor of [his] hands,” rather than accepting a scholar’s stipend.

It is from Chabad.org ([here](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5182627/jewish/14-Facts-About-the-Arizal-Every-Jew-Should-Know.htm)) but where did it find the quote?

Comment: רמב"ם הלכות מתנות עניים פרק י הלכה יח:

לעולם ידחוק אדם עצמו ויתגלגל בצער ואל יצטרך לבריות ואל ישליך עצמו על הצבור,
וכן צוו חכמים ואמרו עשה שבתך חול ואל תצטרך לבריות,
ואפילו היה חכם ומכובד והעני יעסוק באומנות ואפילו באומנות מנוולת ולא יצטרך לבריות,
מוטב לפשוט עור בהמות נבלות ולא יאמר לעם חכם גדול אני כהן אני פרנסוני,
ובכך צוו חכמים,
גדולי החכמים היו מהם חוטבי עצים ונושאי הקורות ושואבי מים לגנות ועושי הברזל והפחמים ולא שאלו מן הצבור ולא קיבלו מהם כשנתנו להם.

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%97_%D7%91

Comment: Are you asking where the expression "the labor of [his] hands" comes from? Can you provide us a relevant link to chabad.org?

Comment: See: Berachos 8a:21 "And Rabbi Ḥiyya bar Ami said in the name of Ulla: One who benefits from his hard labor is greater than a God-fearing person, i.e., one who is so enthralled by his fear of God that he sits idly by and does not work. As with regard to a God-fearing person, it is written: “Happy is the man who fears the Lord, who greatly desires His mitzvot” (Psalms 112:1), while with regard to one who benefits from his hard work, it is written: “By the labor of your hands you will live; you are happy and it is good for you” (Psalms 128:2)."

Comment: And the Rambam, Mishneh Torah, Talmud Torah 3:11 "He who supports himself by the labor of his own hands attains a high degree." And Avot 6:4.